# How to get the time spend on billable tasks and non-billable task on CRM 2016 for each Individual

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I added a field on the Task entity on CRM to keep track of whether the task is billable or not.
Now I want to sum the time spend on the billable tasks and non-billable tasks for each individual.
How can I achieve this in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016?

Comment: How do you want your data presented? In a report, on the individual's CRM User form, in a dashboard..?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with an [aggregated report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/gg309565.aspx) using FetchXML as follows:

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" aggregate="true">
  <entity name = "task">
    <attribute name="actualdurationminutes" alias="durationCount" aggregate="count" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="ownerid" value="userID" operator="eq" />
      <condition attribute="isbilled" value="isBilledTask" operator="eq">
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Replace `userID` with the ID of your User.

Replace `isBilledTask` with 0 for no and 1 for yes.

---

**Notes:**

- The attribute `isbilled` is an out-of-the-box field; you may not have needed to create your own custom field for billable/non-billable.
- `actualdurationminutes` is in minutes and is not automatically calculated (it must be manually input by a CRM User).